# Android: testing logic for users who haven't got google play services, on an emulator

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, emulation, google-signin

I'm trying to test out the logic for users who haven't got google play services on an emulator that I setup (without using Google APIs). As expected, attempting to signin with Google causes a "get google play services" dialog to popup, but pressing on the button in the dialog just causes an error in the logcat of:

> SettingsRedirect: Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services

I want to know if this is only because I'm using an emulator or if it could indicate a bug in my code that could affect users? (i.e. if there is a way of making this button work on an emulator)

Edit: code for my checking gps method:

```
 public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity, String actionWeArePerforming) {

        Timber.i("checkPlayServices: called by %s because of %s", activity.getClass().getSimpleName(), actionWeArePerforming);

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            Timber.d("checkPlayservices: resultcode was not success");

            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {

                Timber.d("checkPlayServices: update available - resolving");

                // "user resolvable" means Google Play is available to download the last version of Play Services APK
                // This will open Google dialog fragment displaying the proper message depending on "resultCode"
                googleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } else {

                Timber.d("checkPlayServices: update not available");

                final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) activity
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

                // Should not happen. This device does not support Play Services.
                // Let's show an ultimate warning.
                Snackbar.make(viewGroup, activity.getString(R.string.cannot_download_google_play_services), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

            }

            Timber.i("checkPlayServices: returning false");
            return false;
        }

        Timber.i("checkPlayServices: returning true");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code. When the dialog pops up for me in the emulator and I click it, it doesn't crash. Just nothing happens.

Comment: it doesnt crash for me either - but it doesnt go to any google play services download page so I'm wondering if this is the extent of the logic that I can test with the emulator or not

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @TimAutin unfortunately nothing beyond what I wrote here

Comment: OK, thanks! I guess we have to do it ourselves...

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing this :

```
 private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    // Get the availability :
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        // Build a popup :
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_problem_alert_title);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.common_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                finish();
            }
        });

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                final String appPackageName = "com.google.android.gms";
                try { startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName))); }
                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) { startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName))); }

                finish();
            }
        };

        // Set the messages according to the most common errors and show the popup :
        switch(result) {

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING : {

                builder.setMessage(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_missing_alert_message);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_missing_alert_positive_button, listener);
                builder.show();

                return false;
            }

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED : {

                builder.setMessage(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_needs_update_alert_message);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_needs_update_alert_positive_button, listener);
                builder.show();

                return false;
            }

            default: {

                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_problem_alert_message).replaceAll("\\$1", googleApiAvailability.getErrorString(result)));
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.main_activity_google_play_services_problem_alert_positive_button, listener);
                builder.show();

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This way :

- if the availability is OK, the method returns true
- if the services are not installed / need an update / have a problem, the method opens a popup
- if the Play Store is not installed, the user will still be able to open the link in its browser

That should be OK, I guess... It's a shame that the out of the box methods provided by Google get the job only half done :/

Of course, you can do even better by starting the Play Store activity with a result and check again in onActivityResult, but I've been lazy on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the emulator, see this issue:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/32